# Check if the sibling node has a text content

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to traverse through the sibling nodes in javascript. I use the document.getElementById and I want to check if its sibling has any text content. If it doesn't I want to check the siblings of the parent node.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function changeSize()
{
var x=document.getElementById("compman");
if (x.parentNode && x.parentNode.textContent) {
alert("My input has a value!");
} 

y=x.nextSibling;
alert(y.nodeValue);
alert(x.parentNode.textContent);

}
</script>
</head>
<body>


<a href="http://sample_url"   id="pd_cp_mov_0_B004JMY312" > 

<img src="http://samplepic.jpg" width="50" alt="" class="faceout" height="50" border="0" id="compman">
<span class="cpAsinTitle">Hocus Pocus</span> 
<div>
sample text
</div>
</a>
<p>test content</p>
<p class="s2"> sample content 2 </p>
<br><br>
<input type="button" onclick="changeSize()" value="Change size of image">

</body>
</html>
```

In the above content, i get hold of the img tag. Now I want to check if its sibling has any text content. In this case, it has the value Hocus Pocus. If it doesn't have a text value, I want to check the sibling of its parent. So the test content should be returned.

Comment: Doesn't it work? Tell us what errors you get

Comment: `x.nextSibling` will likely not be the HocusPocus-span, but the line-break text node between the img and the span elements