# Representing Document DOM in HTML: Sibling Text Nodes

Tags: javascript, html, dom, transformation, prose-mirror

I read this statement from @Bergi in a [very old comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13237843/check-if-the-sibling-node-has-a-text-content) discussing a `nextSibling` value:

> x.nextSibling will likely not be the span, but the line-break text
>   node between the img and the span elements

The example @Bergi was referring to was some script to select the first element in fairly simple HTML, and find the `nextSibling`:

```
<img src="something">
<span>
```

Do browsers insert a "line-break text node" into the DOM between element nodes? What I'm really trying to understand is this comment in an older discussion about serializing a document model to HTML with ProseMirror:

> HTML can almost always be used to fully represent the document DOM.
>   There is one exception we have come across: sibling text nodes. Before
>   using ProseMirror we found it was important to have sibling text
>   nodes, so we serialize the HTML to JSON for storing in the database.
>   We still do that now, for compatibility reasons, but given that we
>   don’t need sibling text nodes any more, this will likely be gone in
>   the next version of our file format.

The rest of the discussion in that thread was voluminous and not related to this question, so I didn't link it. I think the reason this author is saying that HTML can't mirror the DOM in the case of sibling text nodes is because line-break nodes are automatically inserted into the DOM (and not represented in HTML). Is this accurate?

Comment: When HTML is parsed and converted to a DOM, whitespace is collapsed and in some cases removed inconsistently across browsers (e.g. IE will remove redundant whitespace between elements, Firefox will insert an empty text node). That's why you can't guarantee that a serialised DOM will exactly match the source that created it, even in very trivial cases.

Comment: Without knowing what the problem ProseMirror faced, it's hard to tell quite what it means. But line break nodes can be represented in HTML just fine. What it *might* be referring to is representing *adjacent* text nodes siblings. If you have two text nodes in a document next to one another, serialize the DOM as HTML and then parse it back, the resulting DOM will contain one text node at that place, not two. If you wanted to preserve the DOM to the extent of having two text nodes, you'd need to serialise the DOM using a different format, such as JSON.

Comment: @Alohci That sounds like exactly the issue (two adjacent text nodes being collapsed into one). Thanks! It's relevant in ProseMirror because an application may want to maintain the distinction between two adjacent nodes for some future operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the concept of "hidden characters" that you mention is not accurate.
The thing is that nextSibling returns **literally** the next sibling on the dom, which doesn't mean it's going to be the next **element** on the dom. 
If you wanto to try, remove all linebreak characters and try again, or simply use **nextElementSibling** instead.